# Problems working with several gamepads simultaneously in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, xbox, gamepad, ps4

I have two gamepads connected:

- one compatible with PC connected via cable
- one compatible with PS4 connected wireless.

I configured the Input in a way that each button has a different input according to the joystick to which it belongs to.

The first one works correctly while the one with ps4 does not.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Input Mapping

[image]

My config example

[image: My config example]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that this community is in English. I translated your text but next time do it yourself please.

Comment: Does the wireless controller not work at all or only not for Unity?

Comment: I thought i wrote that in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved the problem", basically when you use your ps4 controller in your PC via bluetooth the input mapping changes, so you need a program that translate that inputs into a Xbox virtual controller.